# Help with definition used in description of circle-line intersection

Tags: matrices, geometry

[This page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html) on the topic of circle-line intersection at Wolfram's Mathworld section has this definition:

[image]

I understand the first three definitions, but how exactly does the matrix definition work? What is it defining, and what is its significance?

(Being somewhat unfamiliar to the site, I welcome edits and/or suggestions.)

Comment: That is called the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the matrix. You will learn it when you have your linear algebra course.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thanks so much.